# Test class make dynamically?

Tags: apex, unit-test

below is my test class.

```
@isTest
public class CaseUserHelperTest{

    static testMethod void helperMethod(){


           Datetime myDate = Datetime.newInstance(2017, 24, 3, 10, 50, 0);
           Datetime myDate1 = Datetime.newInstance(2017, 24, 3, 12, 50, 0);

            Test.startTest();         


            Case_User__c cuser1 = new Case_User__c(AvailableUsers__c='00546000000hZWK',Timings__c='2:00PM-11:00PM', SkillSet__c ='Product Support',Availability__c = TRUE,Last_Case_Allocated_Time__c = myDate );
            Case_User__c cuser2 = new Case_User__c(AvailableUsers__c='00546000000hZUx',Timings__c='2:00PM-11:00PM', SkillSet__c ='Product Support',Availability__c = TRUE,Last_Case_Allocated_Time__c = myDate1 );
            insert cuser1;
            insert cuser2;


            Case cas = new Case(Status ='New', Priority = 'Medium', Origin = 'Email',CaseRelatedTo__c='Product Support');
            insert cas;



            Test.stopTest();
            cas = [Select OwnerId From Case where Id=:cas.id];
            System.assertEquals(cas.OwnerId, 'u.id');                     

  }

}
```

In the above test class Availableusers__c is a picklist when going to create a new Case_User__c object record.

for testing i'm passing the Availableusers__c is statically but help me to how a two new users creation and how i make that test class dynamically

Thanks

Comment: You need to be more precise about the `AvailabeUsers__c` field. I guess this is a look up field. But of what type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a method to add new  user

```
public static user createTestUser(){
        list<Profile> p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
        if(p.size()>0){
            User u = new User(Alias = 'testU', Email='stdusr@test.com', 
                              EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Test', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
                              LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p[0].Id, 
                              TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', Username = 'testU@a.com' + System.currentTimeMillis());
            insert u;
            return u;
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

so your above code can be changed to

```
@isTest
public class CaseUserHelperTest{

    static testMethod void helperMethod(){


           Datetime myDate = Datetime.newInstance(2017, 24, 3, 10, 50, 0);
           Datetime myDate1 = Datetime.newInstance(2017, 24, 3, 12, 50, 0);

            Test.startTest();         

user usr1= createTestUser();
user usr2= createTestUser();
            Case_User__c cuser1 = new Case_User__c(AvailableUsers__c=usr1.id,Timings__c='2:00PM-11:00PM', SkillSet__c ='Product Support',Availability__c = TRUE,Last_Case_Allocated_Time__c = myDate );
            Case_User__c cuser2 = new Case_User__c(AvailableUsers__c=usr2.id,Timings__c='2:00PM-11:00PM', SkillSet__c ='Product Support',Availability__c = TRUE,Last_Case_Allocated_Time__c = myDate1 );
            insert cuser1;
            insert cuser2;


            Case cas = new Case(Status ='New', Priority = 'Medium', Origin = 'Email',CaseRelatedTo__c='Product Support');
            insert cas;



            Test.stopTest();
            cas = [Select OwnerId From Case where Id=:cas.id];
            System.assertEquals(cas.OwnerId, 'u.id');                     

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a reusable method to create user

```
public static User createUser(String firstName, String lastName, String profileId){
    String sRandom = String.ValueOf(Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000)));
    User newUser = new User(
                ProfileId = profileId,
                Firstname=firstName,
                Lastname=lastName,
                Username = firstName + sRandom + '@xyz.com',                    
                Alias = firstName.substring(0,2) + lastName.substring(0,2),
                Email=firstName + lastName + '@xyz.com',
                EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
                LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',                    
                LocaleSidKey='en_US',
                TimeZoneSidKey='America/Chicago'
            );
    return newUser;
}
```

In your test method, create the user and pass userId parameter during creation of `Case_User__c` record:

```
Id profileId = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name like 'Profie Name%' LIMIT 1].Id;

User user1 = createUser('firstName', 'LastName', profileId);
User user2 = createUser('firstName2', 'LastName2', profileId);

Case_User__c cuser1 = new Case_User__c(AvailableUsers__c=user1.id,Timings__c='2:00PM-11:00PM', SkillSet__c ='Product Support',Availability__c = TRUE,Last_Case_Allocated_Time__c = myDate );
Case_User__c cuser2 = new Case_User__c(AvailableUsers__c=user2.id,Timings__c='2:00PM-11:00PM', SkillSet__c ='Product Support',Availability__c = TRUE,Last_Case_Allocated_Time__c = myDate1 );
insert cuser1;
insert cuser2;
```